# Peculiar QuerySet behaviour when doing an 'AND' query

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have some peculiar behaviour when making a query. When using an "AND" filter it takes some 20-30 seconds after the query has completed to render to the screen.

The following is a test function I have been using to try to isolate the problem.

```
def reports_question_detail(request, q_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(promo_models.Question, pk=q_id)
    import time
    start_time = time.time()
    question_answers = promo_models.QuestionAnswers.objects
          .filter(question=q_id, promotion__workflow_status=6)
          .values('questionoption').annotate(Count('id'))
    print (time.time() - start_time)
    return HttpResponse(question_answers)
```

I have tried swapping the filter query out, checking the SQL generated and timing how long to execute.

1. filter(question=q_id)
2. filter(promotion__workflow_status=6)
3. filter(question=q_id, promotion__workflow_status=6)

I was expecting the third query to take a lot longer, but actually each of the 3 queries take almost exactly the same time to run. However, after the execution has completed and the debug print shows the time, the third query takes another 20 seconds or so after the query has executed to render to the screen.

I then wondered if there was something wrong with the returned Queryset and tried ignoring the result by changing the following line:

> HttpResponse("Finished!")

... which rendered immediately to the screen for all queries.

Finally, I wondered if there were any differences between the returned Queryset and tried doing a dump of all of the attributes. The Querysets from the first two queries dumped their attributes quickly to the console, but the third one stuttered, taking about 20-30 seconds for each line.

I'm kind of getting out of my depth now. Can anyone suggest how I investigate this further?

Comment: Further to Daniel Roseman's answer. The results for the different filters were: 0.23 seconds, 0.29 seconds and 74 seconds. In addition I have tried running the generated SQL directly in the database and this runs normally. Any more suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QuerySets are lazy. Calling `filter` does not actually do any calls to the database: those are only made when the queryset is iterated. So your `time` calls are only measuring the time taken to define a queryset object.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I just want to elaborate and say you can trigger the evaluation by just wrapping the queryset with iter([queryset]).

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I had heard of the lazy execution thing but I guess I've now learnt the hard way. Given your answer, I adjusted the test code to print the result to console and the updated times are above in the comments. Do you have any further suggestions on why executing in the test code should take significantly longer than directly in the database, where all three queries are almost instantaneous. Or should I post this up as another question?